blender alpha animation
I want to create an animation where an object starts with a transparency of 0 and gradually becomes 100. However, when the transparency is set to 0, there is still something like a shadow remaining. How can I remove it?


Hello have you set the Blend Mode to Alpha Blend?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
